# Trigger next JSON item

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have a main component which has a filter, and loads a list of items.
On click on one of the items my detail component is loaded. Now I want to create a button in my detail component to switch to the next or previous item.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

My list in main.component.html:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td><strong>Nr</strong></td>
       <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody style="overflow:scroll;">
      <tr routerLink="./{{item.id}}" <!-- this goes to my detail-component -->
          ngFor="let item of listItems; let i = index;"
          (click)="setClickedRow(i)"
          [class.active]="i == selectedRow">
          <td >{{item.number}}</td>
          <td>{{item.description}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-pd-ow grid-wo">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-pd-ow">

        <!-- List view component -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ItemComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'list' },
      { path: 'list', component: ListViewComponent},
      { path: ':id', component: DetailsViewComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

In my details component:

```
export class DetailsViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscription: Subscription;
  public id: number;
  public item = new Item();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private itemService: ItemService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        this.itemService.get(this.id).subscribe(item => {
          this.item = item;
        });
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a parent component and a details one.

To pass information to a parent component you can use the EventEmitter, but you will have to create two different components like this :

MainComponent.html :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td><strong>Nr</strong></td>
       <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody style="overflow:scroll;">
      <details-component ngFor="let item of listItems; let i = index;"
          (click)="setClickedRow(i)"   
          [class.active]="i == selectedRow"
          [index]="i"
          [itemId]="{{item.id}}"
          [description]="{{item.description}}"
          (selectSibling)="setClickedRow(siblingNumber)">
      </details-component>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Your new detail component class:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'details-component',
    templateUrl: 'details-component.html'
})
export class DetailsViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Output() selectSibling: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  @Input() index: number;
  @Input() description: string;
  @Input() itemId: string;

  subscription: Subscription;
  public item = new Item();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private itemService: ItemService) {}

     ngOnInit() {
       this.itemService.get(this.itemId).subscribe(item => {
          this.item = item;
        });
      }

      selectNextSibling(): void {
         this.selectSibling.emit(this.index+1);
      }

      selectPreviousSibling(): void {
        this.selectSibling.emit(this.index-1);
      }
}
```

You will have to trigger the selectNextSibling and selectPreviousSibling on click on the respective arrows and do the proper array boundaries checks in your setClickedRow() method :)

Comment: Thanks for the input! 
My list is in my main component, not in my detail component.

Comment: No worries :) Is it not what I implemented ?